# Windows 10 lock-out

Tags: windows-10

With Windows 10, how can I turn off 'Lock-out'?
If I am away from my computer for one minute, I have to re-enter my pin #. I would like to turn this off completely, or extend the time before it locks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the *Start* button.
2. Select *Settings*, then *Personalization*.
3. Choose *Lock screen* from the left pane.
4. Scroll the right pane down and click *Screen saver settings*.
5. Change the screen saver timeout. If no screen saver is selected, computer will just lock after this timeout.